# How to get the operation type in devart MysqlDependency

Tags: devart, mysql-dependent-subquery

I know I can get the table name that recently changed using Devart [MysqlDependency](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql%7EDevart.Data.MySql.MySqlDependency.html) by using the following code.

```
void dependency_OnChange(object sender, Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlTableChangeEventArgs e) {
  string tableName=e.TableName;
}
```

But I want to know, Is there any way to get the operation type like: insert, update or delete?

Iam using c# winforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately MySqlTableChangeEventArgs  does not contain information about the type of event (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE).
[https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlTableChangeEventArgs_members.html](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql%7EDevart.Data.MySql.MySqlTableChangeEventArgs_members.html)

In order to determine the kind of transaction you can do the following:

1. Create triggers for each kind of transaction (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE)
2. The triggers should write the necessary information (timestamp, record id, table name, type of operation, etc…) into a special tracking table
3. Use MySqlDependency for monitoring this tracking table only.
4. In the MySqlDependency.OnChange event handler get the necessary information from the tracking table.